# Bool query not working as expected

Tags: elasticsearch

```
        POST /test/topic/_search
        {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "multi_match": {
                    "query": "Predisposition",
                    "fields": [
                      "_all"
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "multi_match": {
                    "query": "thrombosis",
                    "fields": [
                      "_all"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ],
              "should": [
                {
                  "multi_match": {
                    "query": "cancer",
                    "fields": [
                      "_all"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
```

My understanding of the above query is that it must match on `predisposition` `AND` `thrombosis` `OR` `cancer`, however I'm only getting a handful of documents that match on `predisposition` `AND` `thrombosis`, I was expecting lots of `cancer` documents but have zero. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `must` needs to **always** match. `should` will only give a boost to the score **if** it matches.

Also, there is another case when there are no `must` statements and in this case at least one `should` must match.

I think you are looking for the following, instead:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "multi_match": {
                  "query": "Predisposition",
                  "fields": [
                    "_all"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "multi_match": {
                  "query": "thrombosis",
                  "fields": [
                    "_all"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "multi_match": {
                  "query": "cancer",
                  "fields": [
                    "_all"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you are searching is, documents **must have** predisposition AND thrombosis regardless of cancer because they are inside must filter.
You basically need to wrap your `must clause` inside `should clause` like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "multi_match": {
                  "query": "predisposition",
                  "fields": "_all"
                }
              },
              {
                "multi_match": {
                  "query": "thrombosis",
                  "fields": "_all"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "cancer",
            "fields": "_all"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This will give you the desired results.